# How to add multiple ID in category

Tags: php, yii, foreach

How to add in this code multiple ID category.

I have in **kategorija_id** 5 arrays:

1 - News
2 - Magazine
3 - Kokursi
4 - Grantovi ect..

I whant to display just key 1 and 2

when i add array i just print the first key

```
 $kategorija = Kategorija::model()->findByPk($item->kategorija_**id=1,2**);
```

Thnx :)

**Code update:**

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
          <ul class="thumbnails">
        <?php

        $i = 0;            
        $lastDefault = 0;
        foreach ($ids as $itemId) {
            $item = InfoPaket::model()->findByPk($itemId);
            $kategorija = Kategorija::model()->findByPk($item->kategorija_id);

            if ( $i % 3 == 0 && $i > 0 ) {
                echo "</ul></div><div class='item'><ul class='thumbnails'>";
            }  

            $imageUrl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/infopaket/" . $item->slika;

            if ( !file_exists($imageUrl) || empty($item->slika)) {
                if ( $lastDefault == 0 ) {
                    $imagePath = Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/infopaket/info_paket.png";
                    $lastDefault = 1;
                } else {
                    $imagePath = Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/infopaket/info_paket_redv2.png";
                    $lastDefault = 0;
                }
            } else {
               $imagePath = Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/infopaket/" . $item->slika;
            }

            echo "<li class='span3 thmb-elem'>";
                echo "<div class='thumbnail right-caption image'>";
                    echo "<a class='img-link' href='" . Yii::app()->getHomeUrl() . "?r=infoPaket/clanak&id=" . $item->id . "'><img class='img-class' src='$imagePath'></a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='caption caption-link'>";
                    echo "<div class='naziv'><img class='arrow-img' src='". Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . "/themes/shadow_dancer/images/arrow.png'> " . strtoupper($kategorija->naziv) . "</div>";
                    echo "<p><a class='naslov' href='" . Yii::app()->getHomeUrl() . "?r=infoPaket/clanak&id=" . $item->id . "'><strong>" . $item->naslov . "</strong></a></p>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</li>";
            $i++;
        }

        ?>
          </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Finding multiple categories? If you wish to assign multiple ID's to the same category that is not possible. An ID is an unique identifier, hence the `findByPk`. Where PK defines primary key which is restricted to be unique

Comment: Hi, im what to sort news from two categories. I have 1,2,3,4,5 category ID but i just whant to slider shows ID 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem adding this line of code

```
if ($item->kategorija_id==3 || $item->kategorija_id==4 ) {
```

now code look like this and it works perfect.

```
  <?php 
$lastDefault = 0;
foreach ($ids as $itemId) {
$item = InfoPaket::model()->findByPk($itemId);
$kategorija = Kategorija::model()->findByPk($item->kategorija_id);
if ($item->kategorija_id==3 || $item->kategorija_id==4 ) { 
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/infopaket/info_paket.png" />';
 echo '<h2>';
 echo strtoupper($kategorija->naziv);
 echo '</h2>';
 echo '<h1>';
 echo "<a class='naslov' href='" . Yii::app()->getHomeUrl() . "?r=infoPaket/clanak&id=" . $item->id . "'>";
 echo $item->naslov;
 echo '</h1>';
 echo '</a>';
 echo '</li>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`findByPk()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByPk-detail) accepts first argument as array too. So you can do

```
category::model()->findByPk(array('1', '2'));
```

Also, `$item->category_id` will return only single entry. If your item has multiple categories, than set up relations to categories and then get categories ID's with

```
CHtml::listData($item->categoriesRelationName, 'id', 'id');
```

can use function ($data){return $data->attribtues} too ---------^--- to get all attributes of model

Comment: i try like this

 foreach ($ids as $itemId) {
            $item = InfoPaket::model()->findByPk($itemId);
            $category = category::model()->findByPk(array('1', '2'));

but it just read fist ID

Comment: @EdinPuzic I don't see where you try to use multiple categories in your code. Also, for higher code quality use english names in code

Comment: In this part of code $kategorija = Kategorija::model()->findByPk($item->kategorija_id);